# Bootstrapping Binomial Distribution

Tags: python, statistics, sampling

I am working on a simple problem, I want to write a function that will randomly draw n samples of size q from a binomial distribution (say 60% 1, and 40% 0), and then save the share of 1s from each sample in an array (so that I can analyze that array later). For instance, I would like to simulate, if I drew 1,000 samples each of size 30 from a distribution with 60% 1s and 40% 0s, and I would like as an output an array of length 1,000, where each row represents the share of 1's from that sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of 1s, it will be

```
import numpy as np
sim = np.random.binomial(n=30,p=0.6,size=1000)
```

To actually get the draws:

```
sim = np.random.binomial(n=1,p=0.6,size=(1000,30))
sim.shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(np.mean(sim,axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind thanks. Do you by any chance know how to get the percentage on the y-axis? When use the option density=True, that does not work for some reason.

Comment: draw_means=np.mean(sim,axis=1)
plt.hist(draw_means,bins=50,weights=np.repeat(1/len(draw_means),len(draw_means)))

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Bernoulli distribution ?

```
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
data = [bernoulli.rvs(0.6, size=30) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Comment: if you want to count the "1", then: [sum(bernoulli.rvs(0.6, size=30)) for _ in range(1000)]